# TriadicCensus JUNG 2.0 getCounts() returns negative value for motif 003

Tags: jung

I have nine directed graphs of different metropolitan road networks.

When I use TriadicCensus.getCounts(myGraph) negative values are returned for motif 003 (empty triad) in three of the nine cases.

As I understand from the API the getCounts method should return a count, therefore I cannot understand why it could return a negative value for some of the networks. Am I misunderstanding something regarding the TriadicCensus class?

Answer (score 0):

The array that's returned is 1-based, not 0-based.  My guess (without seeing your graph) is that you're interpreting index 0 as the count for 003; the value in index 0 is actually meaningless.  (See the documentation: https://code.google.com/p/jung/source/browse/trunk/jung/jung-algorithms/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/metrics/TriadicCensus.java)